# JavaFX SceneBuilder Controller

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm following the tutorial for creating a new JavaFX application with SceneBuilder and I'm trying to add a controller class to the .fxml file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/bind-ui-to-logic.htm

However, in the "code" section as described in the tutorial, the controller class text field doesn't exist!

I am using Eclipse with Gluon's version of Scene Builder v 8.1.1.

Where can I connect my .fxml file to my controller Java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaFX scene builder 2: controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060568/javafx-scene-builder-2-controller-class)

Turns out, they moved the controller class field. Oracle's documentation is wayy outdated. Thanks to @MhmdAljobairi who pointed out that it's actually on the left side of the window, tucked away in the expandable lists.